# How do I copy a csv file into a mssql database?

Tags: sql-server, database, csv

I am looking for help to migrate my mysql over to mssql.

I have taken the database from MySQL and created a .csv file.

But from here I get stuck.

I hope you can help me to understand this.

Comment: If you need to import a CSV into MSSQL I would suggest using [the import wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

Comment: @paqogomez i mean, i want to move all my data from MYSQL TO MSSQL.
And i have CSV file.

Comment: That doesnt quite make sense.  You really mean that you want to move your data that is currently in a CSV into mssql right?

Comment: Then the import wizard link that i gave you will show you how to do all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Sql Server Management Studio; connect to your server.
2. Right click your database in Object Explorer, and go to Tasks -> Import Data...
3. In the wizard that pops up, choose a Data Source of "Flat File Source", and browse to your csv file for File Name.
4. For Format, choose "Delimited".
5. For Text Qualifier, type in one double-quote character: ". This is an important step that will let SQL read in strings properly.
6. Depending on your file, check or un-check the "Column names in the first data row"

For the most part, this will import your file in. You may need to tweak some of the settings under the Advanced section if your data has text > 50 characters or numeric characters, but the Preview section will show you how the file looks so far.

Answer (score 1):

[Using Sql Server Import Wizard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUDQT4zdXE0)

```
1) Open Sql Server Managment Studio
2) Go Import Wizard.
3) Point the Wizard at your file (I would recommend saving the csv to excel tho).
4) Map Columns to appropriate datatypes and lengths.
```

Comment: Note that step 4 is non-trivial.  If you have data truncation or other types of things, it can error and abort.

Comment: @BaconBits This is very true lol.  Getting the lengths can be a pain in the butt.